# How to get the correct connection string for c# to teradata?

Tags: c#, teradata

I have been trying to establish connection to teradata.

Since there is already a `odbc` on my computer, for Java the string looks like

`String connURL = "jdbc:odbc:DatabaseName" // and it works!`

---

I need to establish the connection in **c#**.
So I tried

`TdConnection cn = new TdConnection ("Data Source = odbc:DatabaseName; User ID = xxx; Password = ooo;")`

But it did not accept this string.
What is the correct way to write the `Data Source` ? What is the `jdbc` counterpart in **c#** ?

Comment: Have you seen http://www.connectionstrings.com/ ?

Comment: More specifically, http://www.connectionstrings.com/teradata/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using ODBC so you must only specify DSN:

```
DSN=myDsn;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=;
```

The jdbc:odbc is just a designation that the java driver uses and is not carried over to ODBC in .NET.   I would suggest you use ADO.NET if that is an option.

or this for the TDConnection:

```
Data Source=myDsn;User Id=uid;Password=pwd;
```

Comment: Thank you +1 I tried this. And i got `invalid connection string. Parameter name : DSN`

Comment: what is TDConnection?

Comment: Ok, TdConnection is the TeraConnection.  Updating my answer: